# Android sensor data converte to json

Tags: android, arrays, json, kotlin

The json data type I want is

```
{"Sensor":[{"sensorName":"gyro","gyroX":-0.0026132816,"gyroY":0.0076529197,"gyroZ":-5.3145277E-4,"pitch":0.0015855022,"roll":0.0012841108,"yaw":-2.6810385E-4}],
"Sensor":[{"acceleration":"acceleration","accX":0.09337672,"accY":0.08858817,"accZ":9.783007,"angleXZ":0.54685944,"angleYZ":0.51881695}] , 
"Sensor":[{"magneticSensor":"magneticSensor","magX":164.58,"magY":-23.039999,"magZ":-160.62}]
}
```

but

```
{"Sensor":[{"sensorName":"gyro","gyroX":-0.0026132816,"gyroY":0.0076529197,"gyroZ":-5.3145277E-4,"pitch":0.0015855022,"roll":0.0012841108,"yaw":-2.6810385E-4}]}
{"Sensor[{"acceleration":"acceleration","accX":0.09337672,"accY":0.08858817,"accZ":9.783007,"angleXZ":0.54685944,"angleYZ":0.51881695}]}
{"Sensor":[{"magneticSensor":"magneticSensor","magX":164.58,"magY":-23.039999,"magZ":-160.62}]}
```

I wonder how to get it in the data format I want

this is my code

```
fun jsonConverte(i : Array<Float> ,sensorName : String ) {
        var obj: JSONObject = JSONObject()
        var jArray: JSONArray = JSONArray()
        var sObject : JSONObject = JSONObject()

        try {
            if(sensorName.equals("gyro")){
                sObject.put("sensorName" , sensorName)
                sObject.put("gyroX" , i.get(0))
                sObject.put("gyroY" , i.get(1))
                sObject.put("gyroZ" , i.get(2))
                sObject.put("pitch" , i.get(3))
                sObject.put("roll" , i.get(4))
                sObject.put("yaw" , i.get(5))
                jArray.put(sObject)
            }else if (sensorName.equals("acceleration")){
                sObject.put("sensorName" , sensorName)
                sObject.put("accX" , i.get(0))
                sObject.put("accY" , i.get(1))
                sObject.put("accZ" , i.get(2))
                sObject.put("angleXZ" , i.get(3))
                sObject.put("angleYZ" , i.get(4))
                jArray.put(sObject)
            }else {
                sObject.put("sensorName" , sensorName)
                sObject.put("magX" , i.get(0))
                sObject.put("magY" , i.get(1))
                sObject.put("magZ" , i.get(2))
                jArray.put(sObject)
            }
            obj.put("Sensor" , jArray) // jArray 를 json 으로
            Timber.d("Test Checked is obj $obj")
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

In this way, we want to get the sensor data and convert it to json and save it in text 
Can you give me a little advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way to format you JSON data is to make it look like this:

```
{"sensors":[{"sensorName":"gyro","gyroX":-0.0026132816,"gyroY":0.0076529197,"gyroZ":-5.3145277E-4,"pitch":0.0015855022,"roll":0.0012841108,"yaw":-2.6810385E-4},{...},{...}]}
```

This way, it will be much more easy to access and much less redundant. However, if for some reason, you do need to store your json like you mention, then, instead of initializing your obj inside the function, you should initialize it outside and modify it with the function. Like the following:

```
fun jsonConverte(i: Array<Float>, sensorName: String, obj: JSONObject) {
        var jArray: JSONArray = JSONArray()
        var sObject : JSONObject = JSONObject()

        try {
            if(sensorName.equals("gyro")){
                sObject.put("sensorName" , sensorName)
                sObject.put("gyroX" , i.get(0))
                sObject.put("gyroY" , i.get(1))
                sObject.put("gyroZ" , i.get(2))
                sObject.put("pitch" , i.get(3))
                sObject.put("roll" , i.get(4))
                sObject.put("yaw" , i.get(5))
                jArray.put(sObject)
            }else if (sensorName.equals("acceleration")){
                sObject.put("sensorName" , sensorName)
                sObject.put("accX" , i.get(0))
                sObject.put("accY" , i.get(1))
                sObject.put("accZ" , i.get(2))
                sObject.put("angleXZ" , i.get(3))
                sObject.put("angleYZ" , i.get(4))
                jArray.put(sObject)
            }else {
                sObject.put("sensorName" , sensorName)
                sObject.put("magX" , i.get(0))
                sObject.put("magY" , i.get(1))
                sObject.put("magZ" , i.get(2))
                jArray.put(sObject)
            }
            obj.put("Sensor" , jArray)
}
```

That way, your object (obj) will be updated with the new data everytime you call the function jsonConverte with your json object as a parameter. This should work much better.